# Android: Sending game-data from Server to Android Clients

Tags: android, client-server

I'm writing a multiplayer poker game for Android.
The game itself runs on the server (I'm thinking PHP), and clients submit their turn information to the Server one after another accordingly.

Now each time a client submits their turn information, I need the Server to send that data to all the other clients in the game...

So far I haven't figured out how best to accomplish this - I could have each client poll the server every few seconds, to see if the Server has new turn data available, but I'm afraid that this wouldn't be very scalable and the server would soon be overwhelmed (with multiple simultaneous games)...

Likewise the Android services that I've found (like GCM, App Engine with C2DM) for pushing notifications from Server to Clients don't seem efficient for gaming, as they can take anywhere up to 15 minutes for each message...

Is there anything wrong with just using a socket connection, and have the Android client use an AsyncTask to listen on the connection? Or does anyone know of some library that I might use? Whatever method I employ needs to be scalable, reliable and fast (aiming for every player-turn to take no longer than 30 seconds and hopefully quicker...)

I'd sincerely appreciate any advice you have as I'm new to coding this type of thing and I'm on my own. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I worked with others on a similar system and there the communication also was done via Sockets (and a custom protocol).